LinkedList cannot be resolved to a type
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class QueueUsingLinkedList{

  public static void main (String args []){

     Queue<Info> qe = new LinkedList<>();

  }
}

When I am importing the LinkedList I am getting  this error

The import java.util.LinkedList cannot be resolved

LinkedList using Queue or even trying to create a simple LinkedList but it showing me the  error

LinkedList cannot be resolved to a type

but i dont know why only LinkedList is throwing the error
I tried to re-import. Also I checked the syntax.
and compile the code "java ClassName.java"

What version and what edition of Java are you using? It should be there, so if it's not, my guess is that maybe it's because your JDK isn't up to date?

Hello Yash, welcome, 'I tried to re-import. Also I checked the syntax.
and compile the code "java ClassName.java"'... javac ClassName.java is better!!

some ideas: 1) using some strange character like Ⅼ (\u216C); 2) JDK installation error or tampering with; 3) actually no idea what Queue  or Info is (already asked for [mre] (on Staging Ground; ( 4) javac ClassName.java will not help since the file should be named QueueUsingLinkedList.java , at least if posted code is the correct code )

( 5) remotely possible, an own class names LinkedList somehow interfering -- not so clear what the error is A) import cannot be resolved; B) cannot be resolved to a type; or C) both )

@Marce BTW  java ClassName.java will compile and (try to) execute main() of the first class found in that file, if not using some older Java version (Using Source-File Mode to Launch Source-Code Programs . JEP 330)

Please provide a reproducible example. This is not one, as the code posted here works fine and does NOT yield the error you describe.

@user85421, Thank you maestro, it is a piece of information that I did not have, and you have even taken the trouble to post a link to the documentation, people like you, make the difference!!!!

Assuming that Info is one of your classes, and that it exists, I did it this way and received no errors.  A LinkedList can be the constructor for a Queue.
Also, command line compilation is javac not java.  Hoping that is just a typo.
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class QueueUsingLinkedList{

  public static void main (String args []){

     Queue<Info> qe = new LinkedList<>();

  }
}


Calling java instead of javac might not be a typo, as it's actually possible to compile code at runtime in recent versions of java: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html#using-source-file-mode-to-launch-single-file-source-code-programs
